# Can't add record to database after adding ICollection property in a Model class

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Before I have this code:

Department.cs:

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Add Action Method in DepartmentController:

```
        //GET
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //POST
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Add(Department obj)
        {
            if (_appDbContext.Departments.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(obj.Name)).Any())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Department name already exists");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _appDbContext.Departments.Add(obj);
                _appDbContext.SaveChanges();
                TempData["success"] = "Department created successfully";

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }
```

Add.cshtml:

```
@model Department

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Add Department</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>*@
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="mb-1"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Add</button>
        <a asp-controller="Department" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:150px">
            Back to List
        </a>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

The code above worked fine for adding records.
But it doesn't work anymore after this change to the Department.cs class (database dropped and reupdated to ensure fresh start):

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Equipment> Equipments{ get; set; }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I should add the new property in the Controller or View and what exactly to add.

Comment: What's the code of  your  Equipment model ? If you add the new property  in the Department,  not only database dropped and reupdated to ensure fresh start, but also create a new migration too.

Answer (score 0):

If there is foreign key relation between Equipment and Department then the relation should be added like below:

1. The ICollection property should be added like:

   public virtual ICollection Equipments { get; } = new  List();
2. Equipment class should contain navigation properties:

   public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

   public virtual Department Department { get; set; } = null!;
3. Also, Check your _appDbContext for relation.